# JavaScript/jQuery - textchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html- `input type="text"`, and I want to add this tag an event handler that will work when the text is changes. The problem is that this input is getting his value from antoher javascript function and then the event handler isn't working.

*For example*

This is the event:

```
$("#inputid").change(function(){
   alert('bla bla')
}
```

And this what need to raise the event

```
function inputvalue(){
   $("#inputid").val="bla"
}
```

Unfortunately when the value of the input is changing (from the function inputvalue),it doesn't raise the event. If I put the value of the input manually the event is working

Any idea why the javascript doesn't reconize the text change from a script?

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the change event yourself in the `inputvalue` function:

```
function inputvalue(){
   $("#inputid").val("bla").change();
}
```

Also notice the correction of your syntax... in jQuery, `val` is a function that takes a string as a parameter. You can't assign to it as you are doing.

Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sm4cD/) showing the above in action.

Answer (score 0):

Your function has an error. Try this:

```
function inputvalue(){ 
   $("#inputid").val()="bla" 
}
```

EDIT

My function is also wrong as pointed in comments.

The correct is:

Using pure javascript

```
function inputvalue(){ 
   document.getElementById("inputid").value ="bla"; 
}
```

Using jQuery

```
function inputvalue(){ 
   $("#inputid").val("bla"); 
}
```

Comment: Your function has an error too... it should be `$("#inputid").val("bla");`.

Comment: ok I make the right correction but still the event isn't raise when changing the value from the inputvalue function